# WCF WEB API Client Pure Json: Will the use of MemoryStream cause Performace issuse if used in a API call for large amount of data

Tags: json, wcf, wcf-web-api

I have written the following code to return a different Json Object based on the JobId user is passing. 
what i wanted to know was whether using MemoryStream in the Function ReturnPureJson cause any performance related issuse in the WCF API calls?

```
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "{jobId}", Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public Stream GetJobData(Guid jobId)
    {

        object responseData = null;

        //Code to fetch the proper Job Based on the JobId Passed
        Job job = GetJobData(jobId);

        if (job != null)
        {
            switch (job.JobType)
            {
                case JobType.UserData:
                    responseData = GetUserData(); //Returns a List<UserData> where Userdata is a class
                    break;
                case Job.EJobType.ApplicationData:
                     responseData = GetApplicationData();//Returns a List<ApplicationData> where ApplicationData is a class
                    break;
                  //some more case statements to fetch appropriate response
            }
        }

        return ReturnPureJson(responseData);
    }
    private Stream ReturnPureJson(dynamic responseModel)
    {
        string jsonClient = Json.Encode(responseModel);
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonClient));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a MemoryStream?  Why not just return the JSON as a string....

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Json

Public Class JsonConvertor(Of t)
    Public Function FromJSON(ByRef sreader As StreamReader) As t
       If GetType(t).Equals(GetType(String)) Then
           Dim result As Object = sreader.ReadToEnd.Replace("""", "")
           Return CType(result, t)
       Else
           Dim ds As New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(t))
           Dim result As t = DirectCast(ds.ReadObject(sreader.BaseStream), t)
           ds = Nothing
           Return result
       End If
   End Function

   Public Function ToJSON(ByVal ObjectToBeConverted As t) As String
       Dim s As Stream = New MemoryStream()
       Dim ds As New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(t))
       ds.WriteObject(s, ObjectToBeConverted)

       Dim output As New StreamReader(s)
       Dim ostr As String = output.ReadToEnd
       s.Dispose()
       Return ostr
   End Function
End Class
```

This will let you convert any "DataContract" to or from JSON.

Comment: when i use the above method or Json.Encode() then i get Json output which looks like this :
{\"Items\":[{\"Id\":\"a554ee3f-1085-489b-af02-31ff3ba5c52b\",\"Name\":\"AC"}]}

What i wanted was Pure Json without any escape characters :
{"Items":[{"Id":"a554ee3f-1085-489b-af02-31ff3ba5c52b","Name":"AC"}]}

Comment: That's odd... I can't reproduce that with my code above.  Even odder is that it didn't escape the last quote in the object.

Comment: The `\` is used as an escape character in C# strings and maybe there's some kind of automatic escaping going on?